# Enumeration error on results fetched using nhibernate session create sql query

Tags: nhibernate, sharp-architecture

I am using sharp arch ver 1.0.

In the NHibernate PostUpdateEvent I am trying to access database.

```
public class PostUpdateListener : IPostUpdateEventListener 
{ 
    public void OnPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent postUpdateEvent) 
    { 
        var session = NHibernateSession.Current;

        var results = session.CreateSQLQuery("Select * from Storefront").List<object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
        {
        }
  }
```

When I try to save any entity and in the postupdateevent i run this select query, it gives the enumeration error on OnFlush. NHibernate\Listeners\FlushFixEventListener .cs    Line: 35

I read that using foreach loop runs enumeration operation so better to run for loop. But I tried with the for loop. still makes no difference.

The save operation is processed with SharArch NHibernate Transaction attribute. If I remove the Transaction attribute the query in the postupdatelistener works fine.

here is the stack trace.

[InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.]
   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource) +56
   System.Collections.Generic.Enumerator.MoveNextRare() +58
   System.Collections.Generic.Enumerator.MoveNext() +93
   NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list) in d:\horn.horn\orm\nhibernate\Working-2.1\src\NHibernate\Engine\ActionQueue.cs:112
   NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions() in d:\horn.horn\orm\nhibernate\Working-2.1\src\NHibernate\Engine\ActionQueue.cs:147
   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource session) in d:\horn.horn\orm\nhibernate\Working-2.1\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\AbstractFlushingEventListener.cs:241
   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent event) in d:\horn.horn\orm\nhibernate\Working-2.1\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\DefaultFlushEventListener.cs:19
   Infrastructure.NHibernate.Listeners.FlushFixEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent event) in D:\Solutions\Infrastructure\NHibernate\Listeners\FlushFixEventListener .cs:35
   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush() in d:\horn.horn\orm\nhibernate\Working-2.1\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs:1478
   Infrastructure.NHibernate.LinqRepository`1.Save(T entity) in D:\Solutions\Infrastructure\NHibernate\LinqRepository.cs:95
   Tasks.Shared.ContentEntityTasks`4.Save(TSaveEntityRequestDetails details) in D:\Solutions\Tasks\Shared\ContentEntityTasks.cs:96
   Web.Controllers.Entity.EntityController.Edit(EntityViewModel entityViewModel, HttpPostedFileBase fileName, HttpPostedFileBase mainImageFileName, HttpPostedFileBase thumbnailFileName) in D:\Solutions\Web.Controllers\Entity\EntityController.cs:379
   lambda_method(ExecutionScope , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +236
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClassa.b*_7() +85
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +235491
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +235491
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +235491
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +235491
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +288
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +235670
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +174
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext) +209
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +599
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +171

Comment: Is this a multi threaded application?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what is happening is the session is deciding to flush due to the CreateSQLQuery call.  That causes the post update event to be added to the list of internal events that need to be fired (guessing at this one).

You should be able to fix it by accessing a child session, instead of the main NH session, by using the event.  Like this:

```
public class PostUpdateListener : IPostUpdateEventListener 
{ 
    public void OnPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent postUpdateEvent) 
    { 
        var session = postUpdateEvent.Session.GetSession(EntityMode.Poco)

        var results = session.CreateSQLQuery("Select * from Storefront").List<object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

If you also require adding or updating entities inside this event, for the purposes of an audit log for example, then you'll also want to ensure you flush the inner session.